# Angular/html5 defer script attribute - injector error after page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova

I'm building an Angular Cordova App (SPA) which has a lot of script dependancies. To get the app to load(display) in a reasonable time i've increased the App's splashscreen duration to around 7 seconds and added 'defer' attributes to a lot of the scripts. All scripts are sourced from the devices file system.

The majority of the scripts in the App are angular modules.

Example:

```
<script src="/foo/bar.js" defer></script>
<script src="/some/other.js" defer></script>
<!-- Many more scripts -->
```

This works perfectly when loading the app. If I remove the defer attributes from the scripts the app goes from loading instantly after the splashscreen hides to taking anything from 30-60 seconds to load.

Once you open the App it will detect if you're logged in, if you are then it will redirect you to your homepage. The homepage uses a lot of these external dependancies whereas the login page does not.

The problem arises when I refresh the App in the browser whilst developing. Sporadically Angular throws injector errors due to the fact that the dependancy scripts aren't present (the defer attribute).

This makes sense but how do I combat this? I want the App to load in a reasonable amount of time and I don't want the App to throw these sporadic errors in the browser whilst developing.

Any suggestions?